# Get Comment and include from field

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm able to get a comment from the Facebook Graph API using the following url:
[https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/{commentId}/?access_token={pageAccessToken}&fields=id,message,from,comment_count,parent,user_likes,like_count](https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/%7BcommentId%7D/?access_token=%7BpageAccessToken%7D&fields=id,message,from,comment_count,parent,user_likes,like_count)

I get the following data back, notice it does not include any **from** data:

```json
{
    "id": "{commentId}",
    "message": "Message is here",
    "comment_count": 2,
    "user_likes": false,
    "like_count": 1
}
```

The user is the page owner and has the following tasks:

```json
"tasks": [
    "ANALYZE",
    "ADVERTISE",
    "MESSAGING",
    "MODERATE",
    "CREATE_CONTENT",
    "MANAGE"
]
```

I've also added the following permissions via Graph Api Explorer:

- pages_read_engagement
- pages_manage_metadata
- pages_read_user_content
- pages_manage_posts
- pages_manage_engagement

Not sure what to do next to make this work, any advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Does this happen for all comments you check or just a particular one? Did you receive a webhook for the comment and if so did it contain a From or User info?

Comment: Yes, this is on all comments that are not posted by the page admin. I'm not using webhooks for this and the app is still in development.